# Android Actionbar with both back navigation and dropdown list

Tags: java, android, list, android-actionbar

SO here's my problem. I need to customize my action bar in order that the logo from the action bar to go back on activity and by pressing near the logo to open a dropdown list in order to change the views. I've searched for a solution for hours and i got nothing. This is exactly what i'm trying to get:

http://blog.mengto.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/android-actionbar.png

PLEASE help me! Thanks

```
import android.app.Activity;


public class Travel extends Activity {

String[] actions = new String[] { "Gallery View", "Grid View" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_travel);

    // action bar back button

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    /** Create an array adapter to populate dropdownlist */
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getBaseContext(),
            android.R.id.home, actions); //here i am trying to put the home button as the button, but basically i need only the logo to make the back action

    /** Enabling dropdown list navigation for the action bar */
    getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

    /** Defining Navigation listener */
    ActionBar.OnNavigationListener navigationListener = new OnNavigationListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition,
                long itemId) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "This is the: " + actions[itemPosition],
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    };

    /**
     * Setting dropdown items and item navigation listener for the actionbar
     * 
     * HERE IS WHERE THE CRASH OCCURS
     */
    //getActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, navigationListener);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.travel, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add dropdown navigation as shown here: [Click here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Dropdown)

For going back to the activity: [Click here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Home)

Happy coding!